# Signing an apk with a .dat file

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am currently working on an app that I didn't create and need to create a new release apk. I have a .dat file that is supposed to contain a certificate of some sort, but I have no idea how to use it or what the file contains.

I've tried using `keytool` to treat it as a certificate and import it into a keystore, but I get an error: `keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate`

`openssl` doesn't recognize it no matter what I try.

Is there something I can do to figure out what this .dat file is? I'm somewhat new to android development and have only used .jks files to store my keys.

Comment: the best people to answer that are those who gave you that file.

Comment: The comment above is right on. You have to ask them. http://www.online-tech-tips.com/computer-tips/how-to-open-dat-files/

Comment: They don't know either. I'm trying to work with what I have.

Comment: @fretsejaz Did you find any solution for this?